# Count JSON objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, object

Ok so theres this JSON object:

```
    jsontext = {"switches":[{"dpid":"00-00-00-00-00-01"},{"dpid":"00-00-00-00-00-02"},{"dpid":"00-00-00-00-00-03"},{"dpid":"00-00-00-00-00-04"},{"dpid":"00-00-00-00-00-05"},{"dpid":"00-00-00-00-00-06"},{"dpid":"00-00-00-00-00-07"}],
"links":[["00-00-00-00-00-01","00-00-00-00-00-05"],["00-00-00-00-00-02","00-00-00-00-00-03"],["00-00-00-00-00-05","00-00-00-00-00-06"],["00-00-00-00-00-05","00-00-00-00-00-07"],["00-00-00-00-00-02","00-00-00-00-00-04"],["00-00-00-00-00-01","00-00-00-00-00-02"]]}
```

The goal is to count all the dpid objects that exist in it... so I do the following so far:

```
function objectLength(obj) {
  var result = 0;
  for(var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    // or Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)
      result++;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The function that I call to get the amount of dpid's in switches

```
objectLength(jsontext.switches);
```

The issue is, when there is only one dpid for switches like this:

```
jsontext = {"switches":[{"dpid":"00-00-00-00-00-01"}],"links":[]}
```

it counts 0... it doesn't do anything in the for section... for some reason it assume its empty I guess..?

TL;DR why when only 1 dpid of switches exists is the json object it returns 0..

Cheers!

Comment: What you say is not repeatable. You have a trailing quotation mark in your assignment of `jsontext`, so trying to run that would just cause a syntax error. If you remove that, the code will return 1 just as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/uu1mtL0g/ Besides, there is no JSON here at all, what you have is a Javascript object. JSON is a text format to represent objects.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `switches` property *only* seems to contain objects with `dpid` properties, you don't really have to do anything special to count them. Just do this:

```
var count = jsontext.switches.length;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just do by filtering and using the length property.

```
var arr = jsontext.switches.filter(function(x){return x.hasOwnProperty('dpid'); });
console.log(arr.length); // number of objects
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LmaL84j6/)

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: jsontext.switches is not an object - Through Firefox when testing..

Comment: you need to `JSON.parse()` the string to convert it to an object

Comment: @JaredSmith its not json, but just an object.

Comment: @TheLipster glad to have helped! Don't forget to mark it as answer by clicking on the tick if it helped you :)